# SQL Server MAX(Count) from query

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, max

Sample table and data to explain what I'm trying to achieve

```
CREATE TABLE #EMP 
(
    MGR_ID Varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    SITE varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    EMP_ID varchar(7) NOT NULL
)

-- Sample data
INSERT INTO #EMP (MGR_ID, SITE, EMP_ID)
VALUES 
('AA90567','Australia','SS3422'),
('AA90567','Australia','FT4322'),
('AA90567','Australia','ERT522'),
('AA90567','Norway','UR78432'),
('AA90567','Norway','GT43432'),
('AA90567','Norway','HY34565'),
('AA90567','Italy','LT3329'),
('AA90567','Canada','HJ9808'),
('AA90567','Canada','POR878'),
('GF89762','Denmark','SW422'),
('GF89762','Denmark','FGT322'),
('GF89762','Denmark','FRE422'),
('GF89762','Denmark','UBHT432'),
('GF89762','Italy','RGT429'),
('GF89762','BRAZIL','GRTS08'),
('GF89762','BRAZIL','NHYU78');
```

Here is my query

```
WITH cte_mgr AS
(
    SELECT
        MGR_ID, 
        SITE, 
        COUNT(*) MgCnt
    FROM  
        #EMP e
    GROUP BY
        e.MGR_ID, e.SITE
)
SELECT
    MGR_ID, 
    SITE, 
    MAX(MgCnt)
FROM
    cte_mgr
GROUP BY
    MGR_ID, SITE;
```

I want to get just the row with highest counts for each `MGR_ID`. It is possible that the same `MGR_ID` has several counts for more than one SITE. In that case both will be included in the results.

Desired result is

```
MGR_ID  SITE
------------
AA90567 Australia
AA90567 Norway
GF89762 Denmark
```

but I get all the rows.

Comment: Highest for each MGR_ID

Comment: preferably not multiple results. But if there are, I might need to write a subsequent query

Comment: both will be there in the result

Answer (score 2):

You can use a row-numbering solution. `ROW_NUMBER` does not give tied results, `DENSE_RANK` does do so.

```sql
WITH cte_mgr as (
    SELECT 
      e.MGR_ID, 
      e.SITE, 
      COUNT(*) AS MgCnt,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY e.MGR_ID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rn
    FROM #EMP e
    GROUP BY
      e.MGR_ID, e.SITE
)
SELECT
  e.MGR_ID,
  e.SITE,
  e.MgCnt
FROM cte_mgr e
WHERE e.rn = 1;
```

Note that if you wanted only a single overall highest count then you can just use `TOP 1...ORDER BY`

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
  e.MGR_ID, 
  e.SITE, 
  COUNT(*) AS MgCnt
FROM #EMP e
GROUP BY
  e.MGR_ID, e.SITE
ORDER BY
  MgCnt Desc;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wiveugz8)